# How to prevent div from getting cut of when resizing window?

Tags: css, html, position

I have a div on the left side of the browser that shows fine, but once I resize the window's width, it gets cut off on the left side. This is fine, but the browser doesn't provide an option to scroll left to see the rest of the div.

As opposed to a div I have on the right side of the page, where if I shorten the width of the window and that right div gets cut off on the right side, the browser always at least lets me scroll right to see the rest of the div.

How i can make it so on the left side as well? I tried adding a left margin but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try adding

```
body{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This *should* automatically add scrollbars when something goes out of view.

Answer (score -1):

Body margin might be set to something like

```
margin-left: -10px
```

Or something like that. If you have been working with responsive CSS. You might have a setting with the div being positioned left so many px/%